# Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView Android NavigationView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, navigation-drawer

Boa noite pessoal!
   Estou tentando criar uma aplicação com navigationView pwla primeira vez e estou encontrando problemas no momento da chamada da setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); a aplicação consiste na activity main chamando alguns fragments de acordo com o item do menu clicado, poré o erro já acontece no começo da activity ao tentar montar o xml:
activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/dl_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.ramattecgmail.rafah.studying.Activitys.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nv_main"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/header_nav"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_nav" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

menu_nav.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/gi_perfil"
        android:checked="false"
        android:title="@string/gi_perfil"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/gi_abrirA"
        android:checked="false"
        android:title="@string/gi_abrirA"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/gi_consultarA"
        android:checked="false"
        android:title="@string/gi_consulta"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/gi_avaliar"
        android:checked="false"
        android:title="@string/gi_avaliar"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/gi_email"
        android:checked="false"
        android:title="@string/gi_email"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/gi_config"
        android:checked="false"
        android:title="@string/gi_config"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/gi_sair"
        android:checked="false"
        android:title="@string/gi_sair"/>

</group>
```

header_nav.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.v4.widget.CircleImageView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/img_perfil"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/circle_image_header"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/circle_image_header"
    android:src="@drawable/profile"
    app:border_color="#FF000000"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/mrg_imagem_perfil"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/mrg_imagem_perfil"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_nome"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:text="Nome do usuario"
    android:textSize="@dimen/tam_text_perfil"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/tv_email"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/img_perfil"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/img_perfil" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_email"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:text="Email do Usuario"
    android:textSize="@dimen/tam_text_perfil"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/mrg_bot_tvemail"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv_nome"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="@+id/tv_nome" />
```

Style.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

app.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
     defaultConfig {
         applicationId "com.ramattecgmail.rafah.studying"
         minSdkVersion 15
         targetSdkVersion 26
         versionCode 1
         versionName "1.0"
         testInstrumentationRunner 
  "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
   buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
    'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-
core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

//FireBase
//Google
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se o erro estiver ocorrendo, conforme você disse, ao inflar o layout em `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`, me parece que é por conta de você ter duas views como parent no layout (`LinearLayout` e `NavigationView`), quando deveria haver apenas uma. Também parece haver um erro por conta de não haver a declaração dos namespaces usados `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` e `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`.
Para criar um NavigationView, você precisa de um `DrawerLayout` como parent no layout com as duas views que eu comentei aninhadas dentro dele, da seguinte forma:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nv_main"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header_nav"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_nav" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**ATUALIZAÇÃO**

No seu menu `header_nav.xml`, você tem um `android.support.v4.widget.CircleImageView`, que existe, mas não pode ser usada por nós, desenvolvedores.
Na documentação dessa classe, está escrito:

```
/**
 * Private class created to work around issues with AnimationListeners being
 * called before the animation is actually complete and support shadows on older
 * platforms.
 */
```

Você pode usar uma biblioteca externa para criar ImageViews redondas, como essa:
[RoundedImageView](https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView)

Comment: Desculpe, não tinha visto que tinha enviado o arquivo main.xml faltando algumas partes, mas agora está completo, o erro está sendo indicado justamente na linha 29 aonde eu instancio o navigationView

Comment: Muito obrigado ! Era isso mesmo ! O problema estava no header justamente na CircleImageView, fiz a alteração conforme sugerido no seu link e funcionou direitinho ! Muito obrigado !!!